# Coin-op/arcade gaming on topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Just wanted to check if old arcade/coin op gaming is on topic?  I would assume so but wanted to check first.

Answer (score 8):

It should be. The arcade scene is still large, especially for fighting and shoot-em-up enthusiasts. Half the games I play either were coin-op games before they were ported to systems, or were designed fully in the style of coin-op. Give us high-score-board hogs some real love!

For older games, if we can still handle questions about the NES, we can handle older arcade games. There isn't all that much material to ask about those, most of which is now trivia like the question about the names of the Ghosts in Pac-Man. Still knowledge we're good for providing.