# Are questions about modern arcade games on-topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I have a question about the 2014 arcade game *[Mario Kart Arcade GP DX](https://www.mariowiki.com/Mario_Kart_Arcade_GP_DX)*. Specifically, I want to ask how to select the alternate color palettes for characters like Mario, Bowser, and Don-chan.

[This question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/811/181240) implies that questions about older coin-op arcade machines are on topic, but I couldn't find any precedent for more recent arcade games.

Are questions about modern arcade games on-topic?

Comment: I believe the [tag:arcade] tag is suitable for your question.

Comment: or just create a tag for the game in question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see why not. They're video games, after all. Theoretically, someone here likely knows the answer, or knows where to find it.